# Nginx mirroring & return error if any response code is not equal to 200?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I currently have the following configuration:

```
+---------+          +---------+          +-----------+
|         |          |         |          |           |
| client  +--------->+ main-lb +--------->+  nginx01  |
|         |          |         |          |           |
+---------+          +---------+          +-----------+
                                          |           |
                                          |           |
                                          |           |
                                          v           v
                                     +----+----+ +----+----+
                                     |         | |         |
                                     |  web01  | |  web02  |
                                     |         | |         |
                                     +---------+ +---------+
```

Which is mirroring requests from nginx01 to web01 & web02 web servers (not nginx).

Here's my current config for nginx01:

```
location / {
  mirror /mirror1;
  proxy_pass http://web01;
}

location /mirror1 {
  internal;
  proxy_pass http://web02;
}
```

Currently both web01 & web02 are receiving requests ok, but only web01's content is served back to the client along with 200 status code.

The problem is that **if web02 is down, then client won't know about it**.

I need to change this behavior so that if web01 **OR** web02 status code != (not equal) 200/301 then return that status code to the client instead of just 200/301 from web01.

Please note, that web01& web02 are two completely different web servers (not nginx). The only "real" nginx here is nginx01.

Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my original post to be more clear on that.

Comment: `mirror` is not what you use for load balancing or failover. Use `upstream` instead.

Comment: @anx both services have to be able to receive a request simultaneously & process it in a different way.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm not trying to load balance or failover. Both services have to be able to receive a request simultaneously & process it in a different way. But if one of them is down, meaning http response != 200 or 301 & etc then the client must know about it, that's the requirement.

Comment: Ok, then the application is broken and needs to be redesigned.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'd prefer not to disclose the design of the application with you, Sir. I'm trying to get an answer & I've provided my requirements/input data, so, please, either provide the answer or no. Thank you.